# How to place Author and Date under title?

Tags: org-mode

When exporting to html I get the following in the footer:

> Date: 10/6/18
>
> Author: Alan U. Kennington
>
> Created: 2018-10-06 Sat 14:58
>
> Validate

But when when I export it to LaTex the author and date are under the title as they should be. How do I fix this for html? Also, is it possible to remove the "Created" and "Validate"?

Answer (score 5):

> When exporting to html I get the following in the footer:

That's HTML postamble, see [`(info "(org) HTML preamble and postamble")`](http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html).

> is it possible to remove the "Created" and "Validate"?

Yes, use `#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil` or `(setq org-html-postamble nil)`.

> How to place Author and Date under title?

One solution is to use HTML preamble, for example,

```
(setq org-html-preamble-format 
      '(("en"
         "<h1 class=\"title\">%t</h1>
          <p class=\"subtitle\">%d BY %a</p>")))
```

and to avoid showing two titles, you also need to use `#+OPTIONS: title:nil` to discard the default title.

Here is a simple org-mode file

```
#+TITLE: A simple org-mode file
#+DATE: <2018-10-07 Sun>
#+AUTHOR: someone
#+OPTIONS: title:nil html-postamble:nil html-style:nil html-scripts:nil html-doctype:html5
#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5

blah blah blah
```

after setting `org-html-preamble-format` as above, the HTML export will be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- 2018-10-07 Sun 13:18 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>A simple org-mode file</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Org mode">
    <meta name="author" content="someone">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="preamble" class="status">

      <h1 class="title">A simple org-mode file</h1>
      <p class="subtitle">2018-10-07 Sun 00:00 BY someone</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        blah blah blah
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```